# How to check to current broken part count for a given clickhouse MergeTree table?

Tags: clickhouse

The [check table statement](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/check-table) exists to check the table integrity. According to the documentation, it may read all the data in the table. Is there a way to query the current number of broken parts for a given table in an efficient way ? It would be interesting to monitor in order to prevent the `Suspiciously many broken parts` error

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended approach would be to monitor directly the system.detached_parts and system.parts tables. For example:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM system.detached_parts;

SELECT count()
FROM system.detached_parts
WHERE startsWith(name, 'broken');
```

There is also quite a bit of additional information available in `system.parts`

ClickHouse 23.4 also add a column in `system.replicas` for `lost_part_count`:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/replicas

[https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog#new-feature-6] Added a `lost_part_count` column to the `system.replicas` table. The column value shows the total number of lost parts in the corresponding table. Value is stored in zookeeper and can be used instead of not persistent ReplicatedDataLoss profile event for monitoring. #48526 [https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/48526]

Answer (score 0):

> Suspiciously many broken parts error

In 99.99% cases this error is a result of unexpected hardware reboot (check `uptime` of the linux) and all files in such parts/folders have the size - zero bytes.

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/suspiciously-many-broken-parts/

> It would be interesting to monitor in order to prevent the Suspiciously many broken parts error

I don't think you need to do something. Clickhouse monitors and checks parts for corruptness automatically. If a table is replicated it automatically fetches uncorrupted part from another replica.